# Neural net training continuos values

Tags: neural-network

As so many papers describes about that NN can predict stock return I also started looking into this method. I am not able to train NN precisly, my prediction does not match even on the training dataset. I am using technical indicators as input and max value in next 10 days as target vector but trained neural net does not predict precise values even for the training dataset. I think there is some mismatch between  input and output data. Any idea to resolve this or what could be relationship between technical indicator as input and target vector in case of continuos value target vector.

Answer (score 1):

The markets are random you cannot predict them, until you realize that you're just gonna lose money. Those organizations that use NN's successfully, use them in combination with other information such as fundamental analysis.

If your goal is to make money in the markets then I suggest you move on.

If your goal is to learn about and get experience with NN then start with the basics. Start reading about the different types if NN and algorithms to train NN's.
[Heaton Research](http://www.heatonresearch.com/)

Now about your actual question, you say you use indicators as input to your NN, that seems like a bad idea to me, indicators is just representing price action differently, so you should use price action and not indicator-values as input. And I suggest you use a lot more than 10 days price action to train your NN. I'm currently using a NN to filter out possible bad trades. I trained my NN using 50 days of price action.

Comment: What do you mean by price action? Do you mean by price action by buying when this happen and sell when that happen?

Comment: No; price movement, candlstick patterns. [Price Action on Investopidia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/price-action.asp#axzz1oQdgLQEK)

Comment: How do you filter the trades using NN? What target vector you use against 50 days price actions as input?

Comment: Movement against trend; 0 price goes xyz against the trend, 1 otherwise

Comment: Actually I have been interviewed by a company  which asked me to write a strategy by using neural network. Being new in this field, I am unable to get good results. How do you classsify trend so that I can assign 1 to trend and 0 to non trend.

Comment: The trend was part of the dataset I were given, someone had manually graded the trend for about 10 years worth of data. And that's really the only way to do it even though it's not gonna take time.

Answer (score 1):

I also tried with the classification problem where target is buy-sell-hold. I looked in to the next 10 days and create target vector buy-sell-hold signals manually but the classification does not work precisly. It does not predict buy-sell-hold correcly. If I take buy-sell-hold based on last available price it predict correct but if I create buy-sell by looking 10 data points ahead it does not predict.

Similar situatio I am having with prediction problem, It predict values precisly if I use same days return as target and same days TI as input but does not predict precisly when target vector is next 3-4-5 days return.